# Can't receive SMS using Twilio trial account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twilio

Everything was working great few hours back before this error pops up and now I can't receive SMS. Below is the log

```
Started POST "/phone_numbers" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-28 20:24:38 +0530
Processing by PhoneNumbersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "phone_number"=>{"phone_number"=>"+919738437250", "user_id"=>"9"}, "commit"=>"Send PIN"}
  PhoneNumber Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "phone_numbers".* FROM "phone_numbers" WHERE "phone_numbers"."phone_number" = $1 AND "phone_numbers"."user_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["phone_number", "+919738437250"], ["user_id", 9]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "phone_numbers" SET "pin" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "phone_numbers"."id" = $3  [["pin", "4143"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-28 14:54:38.800401"], ["id", 51]]
   (99.4ms)  COMMIT
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4519ms (ActiveRecord: 100.1ms)

Twilio::REST::RequestError - The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts//Messages.json was not found:
  twilio-ruby (4.2.1) lib/twilio-ruby/rest/base_client.rb:124:in `connect_and_send'
  twilio-ruby (4.2.1) lib/twilio-ruby/rest/base_client.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in <class:BaseClient>'
  twilio-ruby (4.2.1) lib/twilio-ruby/rest/list_resource.rb:95:in `create'
   () home/pavan/Roorah/app/controllers/phone_numbers_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

Below is my code.

```
#config/initializers/twilio.rb
path = File.join(Rails.root, "config/twilio.yml")
TWILIO_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(path))[Rails.env] || {'sid' => '', 'from' => '', 'token' => ''}

#config/twilio.yml
development:
from: '+1xxxxxxxxxx'
sid: 'Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe0'
token: '5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa0'

#app/controllers/phone_numbers_controller.rb
class PhoneNumbersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @phone_number = PhoneNumber.new
  end

  def create
    @phone_number = PhoneNumber.find_or_create_by(phone_number: params[:phone_number][:phone_number], user_id: params[:phone_number][:user_id])
    @phone_number.generate_pin
  # Instantiate a Twilio client
  client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO_CONFIG['sid'], TWILIO_CONFIG['token'])

    # Create and send an SMS message
    client.messages.create(
      from: TWILIO_CONFIG['from'],
      to: @phone_number.phone_number,
      body: "Enter #{@phone_number.pin} to verify your phone number"
      )
    respond_to do |format|
    format.js # render app/views/phone_numbers/create.js.erb
  end
end

def verify
  @phone_number = PhoneNumber.find_by(phone_number: params[:hidden_phone_number])
  @phone_number.verify(params[:pin])
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @user.update(primary_phone: params[:hidden_phone_number], verified: true) if @phone_number.verify(params[:pin])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
end
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like where you are loading your config with YAML the Account SID is dropping back to the defaults, empty strings. That's why the URL the stack trace is showing up without your Account SID in:

Twilio::REST::RequestError - The requested resource **/2010-04-01/Accounts//Messages.json** was not found:

Check your config and how you're loading the YAML and what the value of `TWILIO_CONFIG['sid']` is.

Also, an easier way to load the config might be with Rails's built in `config_for` helper. Check out the documentation here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application.html#method-i-config_for

Comment: Can you tell how to change `TWILIO_CONFIG['sid']` with `config_for`?

Comment: You would use `config_for` in place of your code in the initialiser. You would replace it with: `TWILIO_CONFIG = config_for(:twilio)` and then carry on as normal.

Comment: Should I change anything in `phone_numbers_controller.rb`? I've replaced the content in initializer with `TWILIO_CONFIG = Rails.application.config_for(:twilio)` and now get `ArgumentError - Account SID and auth token are required` error.

Comment: As before, it looks like the YAML is not returning any config at all. What do you have in your `config/twilio.yml` file?

Comment: Is that indentation accurate? If so, then your `from`, `sid` and `token` should all be indented underneath `development`.

Comment: Damn! It is indeed the indentation problem. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted!